# Gradle Copy Task Is UP-TO-DATE After Manually Deleting a File

Tags: gradle

I am forced to use Gradle 2.3 in this project.

I am trying to copy a set of dependencies from a custom configuration to a specific dir.

If I delete one of the files manually, Gradle still marks the task as UP-TO-DATE and I end up with an incomplete set of files.

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.zips
    into 'zip-dir'
    configurations.zips.allDependencies.each {
        rename "-${it.version}", ''
    }
}
```

This works as expected in v4.0.2 though.

To work around it I am counting files in that dir.

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        def count = new File('zip-dir').listFiles().count { it.name ==~ /.*zip/ }
        count == configurations.zips.files.size()
    }
    from configurations.zips
    into 'zip-dir'
    configurations.zips.allDependencies.each {
        rename "-${it.version}", ''
    }
}
```

Which issue and version of gradle was this fixed in and is there a better workaround than what I have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can just run it always with

```
outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

or not use a type Copy for your task and

```
task copyFiles {
    doLast {
       copy {
          from configurations.zips
          into 'zip-dir'
          configurations.zips.allDependencies.each {
          rename "-${it.version}", ''
          }
       }
    }
}
```

**Note that this is a workaround not the solution**

Comment: Indeed, you can use a `copy` command in a `doLast` instead of a `Copy` task, but this would just work in the same way as disabling *UP-TO-DATE*-checks for this task. Anyway, this will only be workaround, not a real solution.

Comment: @lu.koerfer he asked about the nicer workaround, it is the way i used to do it, do you know the solution to this? I had that problem in Gradle 2.3 as well

Comment: I didn't say that its a bad workaround (however not necessarily better than his approach), that's also why I removed the downvote.

Comment: @lu.koerfer yes but he asked about a nicer/better/different workaround (debatable) thanks for another pair of eyes tho